# What is the correct type for rechart's Legend content?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts

In an app I'm helping with there is a render of `rechart` charts with a legend as follows:

```js
<Legend
  content={renderLegend}
/>
```

`renderLegend` is defined as the following function:

```js
const renderLegend = (props) => {
  const { payload } = props;

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        payload.reverse().map((entry, index) => (
          <li key={`item-${index}`}>
            <span style={{backgroundColor: entry.color}} />
            <span>{entry.payload.value}</span>&nbsp;{entry.value}
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
};
```

This function suggests that the type for `props.payload` should be something like:

```js
interface props {
  payload: {
    color: string;
    value: string;
    payload: {
      value: string;
    }
  }[];
}
```

In TS, I'd like to type the function `renderLegend` appropriately but this type seemingly does not exist.
The property `content` of the `Legend` component takes a `ContentType` which translates to `ReactElement | (props: Props) => Element` where `Props` *does* contain a `payload` property but if I try and access it I find it doesn't have a `value` attribute.
It's important to mention that this *works* as is, written in Typescript with no typing. I'm trying to add typing to have better acces to this `payload`.

Answer (score 1):

Recharts provides the type Payload. Try:

```
interface props {
  payload: Payload[];
}
```

Don't forget to import if your editor doesn't do so automatically:

`import type { Payload } from "recharts/types/component/DefaultLegendContent";`